# How to change blob container name in Parse Server on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, parse-platform, parse-server

I've deployed managed Parse Server instance on Azure cloud. How do I change storage container name? I can see/change blob storage account in the app's properties in Azure portal but do not see where one can change container name. I need this to share storage account between multiple Parse Server instances.

This is GitHub url:
https://github.com/Azure/parse-server-example

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
var parseServerConfig = require('parse-server-azure-config');
var url = require('url');

var config = parseServerConfig(__dirname);

// Modify config as necessary before initializing parse server & dashboard

var app = express();
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/parse', new ParseServer(config.server));
app.use('/parse-dashboard', ParseDashboard(config.dashboard, true));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || url.parse(config.server.serverURL).port, function () {
  console.log(`Parse Server running at ${config.server.serverURL}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the Storage Tool **Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer** to rename your container. You can also rename azure tables and file shares with this tool. See the release notes [here](http://storageexplorer.com/releasenotes.html).

Generally, right click the container you want to rename, click the **Rename** selection in the pop window.
[image]

Comment: I know how to rename blob containers in Azure. My question is how to tell Parse Server to use storage container name different from default "parse"? I can specify different storage account in parse's settings but there is no way to specify storage container name and by default it uses "parse".

Comment: Have you used https://github.com/felixrieseberg/parse-server-azure-storage module?

Comment: Gary. I've deployed Parse Server as a managed service from Azure Marketplace. It seems to use following code:  https://github.com/Azure/parse-server-example

I've not made any changes to the original code and did not deploy it manually, just picked component from the Marketplace and deployed it.